# Hosting a vue js apllication

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nginx, deployment

I have a Vue.js application that is working fine. I have a domain and subdomain name for the application, and I want to host it. My application is running locally, but when I try to add a subdomain name to it, it shows 500 Internal server errors.  I am trying to host a website for the first time, so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

My Vue.js config file looks like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    // Set up all the aliases we use in our app.
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'chart.js': 'chart.js/dist/Chart.js'
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 6
      })
    ],
    devServer:{
     disableHostCheck: true,
       host: '0.0.0.0',
       port: 8080,
       public : 'spark.innovation.com',
    },
              
  },
  pwa: {
    name:' Dashboard',
    themeColor: '#344675',
    msTileColor: '#344675',
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
    appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: '#344675'
  },
  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: 'en',
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
      localeDir: 'locales',
      enableInSFC: false
    }
  },
  css: {
    // Enable CSS source maps.
    sourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
  }
};
```

```
Nginx server configuration

 server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;
  server_name spark.xxxx.com www.spark.xxx.com;
  root /home/ubuntu/frontend-app;
  index index.html index.htm;
  location / {
    root /home/ubuntu/frontend-app;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }


}
```

I am getting 500 Internal server error.

Any advice or tips to how to solve it?

Comment: Dev server is for development. You don't need it to host an app. For production there's `build` command, and then `dist` dir is deployed to a server. If you don't have one yet, you need it.

Comment: Hi Thanks. So I dont need devServer part in my app right? Without that my app is running fine on http://192.168.1.7:8080/. But how to add domain name to my app?

Comment: I am deploying it on nginx server. Is it ok to add our domain name only on server configuration on nginx but not on local application.

Comment: Yes, it's ok, `public` with your domain is needed if you're restricted to other services that depend on website url in dev mode. You'll need to route the domain to the machine where you  run Vue CLI any way, likely through hosts file. Otherwise you don't need it.

Comment: Hi @Estus Flask, I have edited my question by adding nginx server configuration. I am getting 500 Internal Server error on that. How can I solve the issue?

Comment: For Vue part, make sure that /home/ubuntu/frontend-app content is the content of `dist` dir, i.e. there's no nested /home/ubuntu/frontend-app/dist . If the error persists after you reloaded nginx service, check nginx logs. This is totally Nginx question at this point, not Vue.

Comment: Hi Sorry for that. But I have dist folder locally but I cannot find it in home/ubuntu/front-end-app. Is that causing errors? and  Like you said earlier, route the domain to the machine where you run Vue CLI likely through hosts file, I don't get that part much. can you explain little clear.

Comment: Yes, it likely causes errors. It won't be uploaded by magic to webserver, you need to put these files there.

Comment: See what hosts file does in windows. If you need foo.bar.com:8080 to route to local server that runs at 127.0.0.1:8080,  this needs to be done explicitly. The most simple way is to specify their connection in hosts file. Here you don't need it. Just run it locally at localhost:8080

Comment: It means create a dist folder inside home/ubuntu/app and copy  files from local disc to disc folder in ubuntu ?

Comment: @Estus Flask, can u please explain me how to put files to dist folder on ubuntu

Comment: You can do this with FTP, or else. Basic operations with remote servers is outside the scope of SO. You need to NOT have `dist` in /home/ubuntu/frontend-app, I already said this above. You need to put the contents of `dist` into /home/ubuntu/frontend-app . I.e. there's dist/index.html, and it should become /home/ubuntu/frontend-app/index.html on remote server, etc

Comment: Hi @Estus Flask, Thank you so much for your patience and detailed explanation. Really I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Vue CLI assumes your app will be deployed at the root of a domain, e.g.`https://www.my-app.com/`. If your app is deployed at a sub-path, you will need to specify that sub-path using this option. For example, if your app is deployed at `https://www.foobar.com/my-app/`, set `publicPath` to `'/my-app/'`.

Morever you need to configure you web server, where you are trying to deploy you Vue app.

Nginx Conf (Minimal)

```
server {    
        listen  80;
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

Reference - https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath
Deployment - https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

Comment: I am trying to deploy my app using nginx server. Is it necessary to add my domain name to locally running app or I have to just mention it on server configuration.

Comment: Not necessarily, nginx by default looks into root - ```/usr/share/nginx/html; ```. You need to copy the contents of your ```dist``` folder to ```usr/share/nginx/html```

Comment: @AfrinGaffar I have updated my answer with nginx conf for your help.

Comment: Hi @power-cut, Thanks for your answer. How to locate the root on server. If I give pwd, it shows home/ubuntu/frondend-app.

Comment: Assuming that you are running ubuntu. You may want to run some basic linux commands to explore to explore file system.